# Handy Table for operations between tensor product, localization, quotient, fraction field, set minus, direct sum, and associated prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

I'm learning commutative algebra in preparation for algebraic geometry, and the multiple operations between different rings, ideals, and modules frequently overwhelm me. I'm curious whether there is a thorough table that details all of the different identities between the various operations such as:

- $(L/N)/(M/N) \simeq L/M$
- $(M_1 + M_2)/M_1 \simeq M_2/(M_1 \cap M_2)$
- $S^{-1}(M/N) \simeq (S^{-1}M)/(S^{-1}N)$
- $M_p \simeq M \otimes_A A_p$
- $M_p \otimes_{A_p} N_p \simeq (M \otimes_A N)_p$
- $S^{-1}(Ann(M)) \simeq Ann(S^{-1}M)$, $M$ finitely generated
- $k(p) \simeq A/p \otimes A_{A \setminus p}$
- $Ass(\bigoplus M_i) \simeq \bigcup_i Ass(M_i) $
- $A \otimes_R S^{-1}R/\mathfrak{p} \simeq A/\mathfrak{p}A \otimes_{R/\mathfrak{p}} S^{-1}R/\mathfrak{p}$
- And more...

Any source will be much appreciated!